# Storing many dates for many products in a database

Tags: database, database-design

I currently have 'many' products (6k to 14k) stored in a database. I now need for each of the products a price history, to be specific: 20 prices per day.

In a relational database, I would use 2 tables where one describes an item and the other one describes the price at a specific time.

So 1 product has 1 price history.

Would be an appropriate approach to use a relational database for this (in a few months, there are millions of datapoints in the database) or would you use e.g. influx if that suits?

Answer (score 0):

If you have other fields related to the date, then you need *three* tables:

- Product (grandparent)
- DateHistory (child to Product, parent to PriceHistory)
- PriceHistory (child to DateHistory, grandchild to Product)

The middle table holds the date, the third table holds the time-of-day, with a foreign key to DateHistory.

If you have no other columns along with the date, then collapse to two tables.

- Product
- PriceHistory (columns include a primary key, a foreign key to Product, the date, the time of day, the price)

In this two-column scheme, if you need to represent twenty prices at various times on a date, you have twenty PriceHistory rows that happen to share the same date value.

If your database offers robust date-time handling facilities, then you could combine date and time together into one field. Let the database group by date when needed using its ability to understand the date-time values.